# Using KeyPaths on associatedtype objects

Tags: swift, generics, vapor, associated-types, swift-keypath

I am making a backend using Vapor 3 and Swift 5.
On some part I'm trying to use a `KeyPath` on an associatedtype like so:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
  associatedType T: Model & Parameter
  // Some more declarations
}

extension MyProtocol where T.ID: Parameter {
  func myFunction(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<T> {
    return try req.content.decode(T.self).flatMap { t in
      //Do some stuff
      let myId = t[keyPath: T.ID] //Value of type Self.T has no subscripts
                                  //Cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label
      //Do some more stuff
    }
  }
}
```

But I get that `Value of type Self.T has no subscripts` error. I looked and according to this: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md the `keyPath` subscript is defined on an extension to `Any`, and I would asume a `T` should also be an `Any`.

In `Any` way (<- I had to ), I'm sure I've seen `keyPath`s being used on generics (I don't fully understand how generics and associatedtypes are different). So does anyone have an idea what might cause the `keyPath` subscript to be unavailable in this case? Is it just because it is an associatedtype, is there any way I can make this work?

**Update**

If I erase the type of `t` by casting it to `Any` I still get the `no subscripts` error, if I cast it to `AnyObject` I don't get the subscripts error but I still get the `Cannot create a single-element tuple` which I don't understand, since I am not trying to make a tuple, I'm using a subscript.